# recording of timein and timeout in php

Tags: php, mysql

> I'm trying to make an attendance monitoring wherein a person can timein and timeout as many as he/she wish as long as it will be recorded to the database.

```
id   idnumber    datein      timein     dateout     timeout

1     123      2013-02-21   08:00:01   2013-02-21   11:12:45

2     456      2013-02-21   10:15:01   2013-02-21   05:30:01

3     123      2013-02-21   06:58:52   2013-02-21   03:20:16

4     123      2013-02-21   10:05:35   2013-02-21
```

> Can anyone give me an insert/update codes in php?
>
> I have this code that can insert idnumber if not exist and update if exist.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tblattendance WHERE idnumber='".$_POST[idnumber']."'";
$res = mysql_query($query);
list($exist) = mysql_fetch_array($res);

    if (!$exist){
          $query = "INSERT INTO tblattendance SET idnumber='".$_POST['idnumber']."', datein=CURDATE(), timein = CURTIME()";
          $insert_result = mysql_query($query);
    }else{
         $query1 = "UPDATE tblattendance SET dateout=CURDATE(), timeout = CURTIME() WHERE idnumber='".$_POST['idnumber']."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ";
         $insert_result1 = mysql_query($query1);    
    }
```

> What I want is I can insert same idnumber without updating the old record. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Create a composite ID key. Which is a unique constraint over two columns - `idnumber` + type where type is e.g. 0 = in, 1 = out.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
   id INT PRIMARY KEY,
   idnumber INT,
   type TINYINT(1),
   UNIQUE KEY idtype (id, type)
);
```

Comment: Actually idnumber is a foreign key in the tblattendance

Comment: If it's a foreign key and you need to have 2 records for one idnumber, than you have to add another table with (idnumber as PK) between those, and `idnumber` would be a FK from `foo` to this new table's PK.

Comment: At least if you want to keep normalized schema and FKs.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your ideas. I finally got it :)

Comment: On Stack Overflow, one thanks by clicking the green "Accept" check ;-)